# Strange method arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, arguments

Recently I came across a method, which looks like: `add(1).(2)`.
It was on Code Wars. I just should take this 2 argumenst and make them equated 3. It's easy part, I think, but I have never seen any arguments like this(I am newbie).

Do you have a source where I could read about it? Or could you explain it?

If you need more information, I take this example from here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/539a0e4d85e3425cb0000a88/train/ruby

Comment: post real, reproducable code sample

Comment: @Andrey Deineko, did it)

Comment: Note that `add(1)(2)` isn't a valid Ruby syntax.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Don't ask us to go to another site to get the information. Instead, you need to show us the minimal code that demonstrates what you are asking about. Links rot then break, and when they do your question will make no sense.

Comment: At least be sure you show it correctly. The example at the link shows `add(1).(2)` not `add(1)(2)`, over on the right it shows Example tests:  `Test.expect(add(1).(2).(3) == 6);`

Comment: The code you posted is not syntactically valid Ruby code. There is no possible way to make it work. It is legal, and in fact trivial to implement, in Python, ECMAScript, PHP, Scala, R, AmbientTalk, CoffeeScript, Converge, Dart, Dylan, E, Erlang, Falcon, Groovy, Hack, Ioke, Io, Julia, Lua, Monte, Neko, Perl, Perl6, Piko, Pike, Potion, Seph, and probably many others.

Comment: Their question initially asked for `add(1).(2)` which is valid Ruby code, they later edited their question for an unknown reason. I reverted that edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shorthand notation to call a proc or lambda expression

```
proc.call(arg)
proc[arg]
proc.(arg)
proc::(arg)
```

Are all equivalent.

Actually this works with any object that responds to `call` since Ruby is duck-typed like that.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear! Maybe best up vote the answer then and mark it with the checkmark.

Comment: Please don't ask for up votes or to be the selected answer. It's considered bad form. If, after a couple days a poster hasn't selected an answer, then posting a comment under the question suggesting that selecting an answer is proper. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287723/128421

Comment: @thetinman when a new user comments with "thank you" it's obvious that they want to give credit but are not yet familiar with how to do so on Stackoberflow. Your link talks about answers that are begging for upvotes.